# Firebase SDK (Web) create a password-based account

Tags: javascript, web, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used Firebase SDK (Web) for user login in.

Here is a link

[Authenticate with Firebase using Password-Based Accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth)

I used this code for created user account and i can success to create user.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
});
```

But my question is how to decide if create success?

If created fail the code can catch error but if success how can i catch?

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
}.catch(success){
  // Handle Success here
  // I want to catch success like this
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` returns a so-called promise. A promise can succeed and fail and has separate clauses for each. You can handle success with the `then()` clause:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(success){
  // Handle Success here
}).catch(function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
};
```

The reason you don't see `then()` in the documentation, is because the above misses a few important flows for when the user signs in.

For example: what happens if you reload the page/app? Firebase automatically persists the user's session to local storage, but the code is not aware of that. So your app will likely require the user to sign in again, which leads to a not-so-good experience.

With Firebase Authentication it is better to [*monitor* the authentication state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

This callback not automatically gets called whenever the user is signed in or out. So whether you created the account, they reloaded the page or their short-lived token was refreshed - the code in the first block will execute. Similar: whether the user's session expired, they signed out or for some other reason they get signed out - the code in the second block will run.

In this way you only have a single place for handling the case where the user gets signed in or signed out.

But since `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` can fail in all kinds of spectacular ways, you'll still want to handle those error there explicitly.

So the complete idiomatic code for handling the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` and monitor sign-in state is:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
};
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```